# Fill content of a roulette wheel

Tags: javascript, css, geometry

I have roulette wheel (as an image) without numbers. I want to dynamically fill the numbers of a roulette wheel at the right positions and with the right angle. I want to absolute position the numbers on that image.
My wheel image is 1000 x 1000 pixel.

I try to set the positions and angles with a loop, but the positions are not linear and (in my non-mathematical eyes) to random.

```
const roulette_arr = []; //contains als numbers in right order. 0..32..15..19...
for (let i = 0; i < roulette_arr.length; i++) {
    let degree = 10 + (i * 10); //360 degree / 36 Numbers
    let position_x=...
    let position_y=...

    //function do all the stuff later
    setNumber(roulette_arr[i], degree, position_x, position_y);
}
```

I think angle works, but position is still a problem. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: A roulette wheel isn't random, only it's position and the ball inside it are. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Add more information. I am unable to understand your problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette#Roulette_wheel_number_sequence

Comment: Also, there are 37 numbers...

Answer (score 0):

It's trigonometry. Is there a bigger problem?

```js
var can = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
var numbers = "0-32-15-19-4-21-2-25-17-34-6-27-13-36-11-30-8-23-10-5-24-16-33-1-20-14-31-9-22-18-29-7-28-12-35-3-26".split("-");
var cx = can.width / 2;
var cy = can.height / 2;
var cr = Math.min(cx, cy) * 0.9;
//
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  var angle = i / numbers.length * 360;
  var rad = i / numbers.length * Math.PI * 2 - Math.PI / 2;
  var x = cx + Math.cos(rad) * cr;
  var y = cx + Math.sin(rad) * cr;
  ctx.fillText(numbers[i], x, y);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="can">oh no</canvas>
```